# Uploading IPA to apple with altool not working

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

So I'm trying to upload my ipa to apple. but this stopped working...

```
xcrun altool --upload-app -f ./dist/myapp.ipa -t ios --apiKey "KEY_HERE" --apiIssuer "ISSUER_HERE"
```

I'm getting:

> ```
> Request ID: FTP34GRCKE5NK6HNMWTJXEN7.0.0
> 2019-10-22 10:39:33.371 altool[72993:10589325] *** Error: Errors uploading './dist/myapp.ipa': (
>     "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=-1011 \"Authentication failed\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Authentication failed, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to authenticate for session: (\n    \"Error Domain=ITunesConnectionAuthenticationErrorDomain Code=-26000 \\\"The server returned an invalid response. This may indicate that a network proxy is interfering with communication, or that Apple servers are having issues. Please try your request again later.\\\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The server returned an invalid response. This may indicate that a network proxy is interfering with communication, or that Apple servers are having issues. Please try your request again later., NSLocalizedDescription=The server returned an invalid response. This may indicate that a network proxy is interfering with communication, or that Apple servers are having issues. Please try your request again later., NSLocalizedFailureReason=App Store operation failed.}\"\n)}"
> ```

But when I log into iTunes connect the key is still valid. I have no idea why this isn't working any longer. I thought it might be the Key, but I made a new one and still get the same error.

> ```
> xcrun version 48.
> Xcode version Version 11.1 (11A1027)
> ```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem using the Xcode Organizer in V11.1.  I've reported it to Apple.  As a workaround, I reinstalled Xcode 10.3 so I can use the App Uploader, which does work.

Also, Apple appears to have turned the App Uploader into a new app in the App Store called Transporter.  I haven't tried it but I suspect that works too.

Comment: @pstoppani - Transporter works! thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The error `Authentication failed` typically hints that you have provide wrong credentials.

What did you use for **--apiIssuer "Issuer_Here"**?

- Don't use a mail address for "Issuer_Here"
- You can find the **issuer ID** on https://itunesconnect.apple.com/access/api (top part of the page, below sections People/keys)

Answer (score 0):

I think you use some network proxy, you should close the network proxy then it should work.

I had the same problem and retried with closing my network proxy (v2ray proxy).